# ignore or avoid "undefined field" error with Solr dynamic schema field

Tags: solr

In my Solr schema, I have a dynamic field which may or may not exist on documents:

```
<field name="removed_*" type="pdate" sortMissingLast="true" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" uninvertible="true" omitPositions="true" />
```

All of my searches must check that the field is **not** present:

`-removed_${uuid}:[0 TO *]`

When I search this on documents that don't yet contain that UUID, I get an error:

> "undefined field: "removed_65bc705e-2bf7-4ba5-8809-bf84e8538e62"

Is there a way to avoid this without programatically checking the dynamic schema (`schema/fields` API) beforehand?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest providing more detailed steps to reproduce the error.

I tried using the Solr 9.0.0 admin panel "Schema Designer" tab.

```
* click: "[+] New Schema"
** New Schema: dynFieldSchema3
** Copy From: _default
** click "Add Schema"

* Paste sample document
<add>
  <doc>
    <field name="identifier">1</field>
  </doc>
</add>
** click Analyze documents

* click "Add Field"
** name: removed_*
** field type: pdate
** [x] stored
** [x] indexed
** [x] uninvertible
** [x] docValues
** [x] multivalued
** Omit Options/[x] omitPositions
** Sort Options/[x] SortMissingLast
** click "Add"

("removed_*" now appears under "Dynamic Fields" after "random_*")

* Query Tester:
** Query: *:*
** click "Run Query"
** Query Results: 1 hit, a document with identifier 1

* Query Tester:
** Query: -identifier:1
** click "Run Query"
** Query Results: 0 hits

* Query Tester:
** Query: -removed_65bc705e-2bf7-4ba5-8809-bf84e8538e62: [0 TO *]
** click "Run Query"
** Error: Invalid Date String:'0'

* Query Tester:
** Query: -removed_65bc705e-2bf7-4ba5-8809-bf84e8538e62: [2000-01-01T00:00:00Z TO *]
** click "Run Query"
** Query result: 1 hit, a document with identifer 1
```

So the query prohibiting the dynamic field seemed to work for me.

I did get the error once when I mispelled the dynamic field as
remove_* instead of removed_*, but it looks correct in your schema
field.  Are you sure the queried collection is using that schema?